# Rails form: auto-set a future date based on date set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

My Rails form asks users to input a start date for an event, and then an end date for the same event. I am setting the default start date to Time.now

Is it possible to that the user can only ever choose an end date that occurs ON or AFTER the start date? (so when they change the start date, the end date auto-updates)?

My Events controller:

```
def new
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    # set date_start field to be today's date
    @event.date_start = Time.now
    @event.date_end = @event.date_start     
end
```

Form (shortened...)

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>  
    <%= f.label :date_start, "Start date" %>
    <%= f.date_select(:date_start, :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' }) %>             

    <%= f.label :time_start, "Start time" %>
    <%= f.time_select :time_start, { :minute_step => 5 } %>                             


    <%= f.label :date_end, "End date" %>
    <%= f.date_select(:date_end, :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' }) %>   
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll end up using Javascript to do this.  You might look into using a javascript datapicker to help.  There are a number of them out there and they all allow ranges, here's an example:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent users to save events with `date_end < date_start` in your `event` model with `validate`. Users still will be able to choose incorrect date in your field, but they won't be able to save such an event to database.

If you want to prevent them even to choose an incorrect `date_end` you need to use JS here, as Swards told below. jQuery UI Datepicker is a good solution for it.

If `validate` in model will be enough for you, I think it should work (I haven't test it):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :date_end, :date_start, ...
   validate :incorrect_date_check, :on => :create
.
.
.
private

def incorrect_date_check
   if date_end < date_start and date_end < Date.today
      errors.add("Incorrect end date!")
   end
end
```